# How to make the counter variable retain its value after changing it?

Tags: java, instance-variables

This is a code to print out the no. of prime numbers from a set of numbers entered by the user program stops when 0 is entered. The variable counter is not getting updated and result remains 0. How to update the value of counter ?

```
class Prog4 {

    public static void main(String a[]){
        int c=0;
        //int[] array=new int[10];
        int counter=0;
        Scanner b=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the numbers");
        c=b.nextInt();
        while(c!=0){
            boolean y=false;
            for(int j=2;j<c;j++){
                if(c%j==0)
                    y=true;
                }
            if(y=false){
                counter++;
                //array[counter-1]=c;
                }       
            c=b.nextInt();
            }
        System.out.println("No. of prime numbers entered :" + counter);
        //System.out.println("The prime numbers are : ");
        //for(int x:array) 
            //System.out.println(x);    
    }

}
```

Comment: `y == false`, not `y = false`. The former is a comparison, the latter is an assignment. Since you `y` is false after `y=false`, the conditional is not run. However, don't use `if (y == false)` either, use `if (!y)`, which avoids the accidental assignment.

Comment: bcz your condition is while(c!=0) and so it doesnt enter the loop and hence th ecounter is not updated

Comment: ... and this is the reason why the constant expression should stay on the left side when values are compared (`if (false == value)`), even in Java.

Comment: adding to @AndyTurner, if you would have debuged your code you could have noticed that it never gets into the `if(y=false)` clause because of the mentioned reason. Also rather write `if(!y)`, it´s more readable (for me atleast)

Comment: @KevinEsche I suspect that's just because you're familiar with Java idiom. "if y is false" is what you're trying to express, so it might be more natural to a beginner to try to write `if (y == false)`, since you express "if i is 0" as `if (i == 0)`.

Comment: @Turing85 [Your view is not universally shared](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/16908/doesnt-if-0-value-do-more-harm-than-good).

Comment: Hint: just to make that point clear: this is a very simple error; and you could have found that **easily** by some "debugging" effort. Putting your code up here doesn't count as "debugging".

Comment: @AndyTurner Nor universally shunned. Consistently using this my code is. Reason: `! x` is less visible to me than `false == x`

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi "Consistently using this my code is" Sound like Yoda you do ;)

Comment: @theCurious1 follow the solution in other comments, but I have one suggestion, you're computing if 'c' is prime by checking is c is divisible by every number from 2 to c-1, you could reduce this, by checking the divisiblity with no. from 2 to Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(c)) [till the largest closest square root of the number].. This should reduce the time for a very large prime number..Although am not aware of the computational overhead of the square root function..

Comment: @AndyTurner Can be worse. Imagine going Forth and speaking Polish in reverse

Answer (score 0):

Do it:

```
public class Prog4 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int c = 0;
        int[] array = new int[10];
        int counter = 0;
        System.out.println("Enter the numbers:");
        do {
            Scanner b = new Scanner(System.in);
            c = b.nextInt();
            boolean y = false;
            for (int j = 2; j < c; j++) {
                if (c % j == 0)
                    y = true;
            }
            if (y == false && c != 0) {
                counter++;
                array[counter - 1] = c;
            }
        } while (c != 0);
        System.out.println("No. of prime numbers entered:" + counter);
        System.out.println("The prime numbers are: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
            System.out.println(array[i]);
    }

}
```

Input:

```
Enter the numbers:
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
0
```

Output:

```
No. of prime numbers entered: 6
The prime numbers are: 
1
2
3
5
7
11
```

Basically, it was wrong:

1. The scanner was outside of the loop;
2. And you were using "if (y = false)" instead of "if (y == false)".